# Неправильно резолвится имя

Tags: macos, dns

Настроил bind на своем сервере по этой [инструкции](http://nixway.org/how-to/ustanovka-i-nastroika-bind9-na-debian-jessie/)

Сначала все было хорошо, но потом перестало нормально работать. Сейчас, когда делаю ping - мне говорит, что домен лежит у меня локально, то есть выдает 127.0.0.1.

В браузере домен открывает, но не ту страницу, что лежит на сервере, просто пустую

Открываю на своем ноутбуке.

Содержимое файла ***/etc/resolv.conf***

```
#
# Mac OS X Notice
#
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

Файл ***/etc/hosts*** слишком большой, но там точно нету ни моего домена ни ip адреса

запустив на сервере tcpdump -nn 'port 53' получаю

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:32:20.573548 IP 74.125.46.5.60391 > 5.9.39.171.53: 36322 [1au] AAAA? w4u.com.ua. (50)
13:32:20.573740 IP 5.9.39.171.53 > 74.125.46.5.60391: 36322* 0/1/1 (85)
13:32:21.054549 IP 74.125.46.7.48455 > 5.9.39.171.53: 3169 [1au] MX? w4u.com.ua. (50)
13:32:21.054743 IP 5.9.39.171.53 > 74.125.46.7.48455: 3169* 0/1/1 (85)
13:33:03.815489 IP 74.125.46.11.63214 > 5.9.39.171.53: 16086 [1au] AAAA? w4u.com.ua. (39)
13:33:03.815678 IP 5.9.39.171.53 > 74.125.46.11.63214: 16086* 0/1/1 (85)
13:33:03.937458 IP 74.125.46.10.34917 > 5.9.39.171.53: 60364 [1au] MX? w4u.com.ua. (50)
13:33:03.937631 IP 5.9.39.171.53 > 74.125.46.10.34917: 60364* 0/1/1 (85)
13:33:26.736812 IP 5.9.39.171.10641 > 8.8.8.8.53: 58998+% [1au] PTR? 188.198.175.61.in-addr.arpa. (56)
13:33:26.751585 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 5.9.39.171.10641: 58998 NXDomain 0/1/1 (113)
```

запустив команду на ноутбуке host w4u.com.ua получаю

```
w4u.com.ua has address 127.0.0.1
```

хотя запустив команду на другом своем сервере получил правильный ip

Comment: уточните (прямо в вопросе), на каком копьютере вы выполняете команду `ping ...`. приведите содержимое `/etc/resolv.conf`, `/etc/hosts` на этом компьютере, и результат команд `$ hostname` и `$ hostname --fqdn` на этом же компьютере.

Comment: @Diefair, "nameserver 192.168.0.1" - это чей адрес? Наверное с него ж вам и отдаётся не тот адрес?

Comment: Эм, в tcpdump должна быть ещё запись "А? w4u.com.ua". У вас точно нет записей о w4u.com.ua в /etc/hosts? Может быть стоит nscd (демон кеширования DNS), или DNSmasq, или локальная копия bind'а?

Comment: вроде ничего такого нету

Comment: @Diefair, тогда уточните ещё по поводу записи "nameserver 192.168.0.1" - кому этот адрес принадлежит? Что и как там настроено? Имею в виду то, что может относиться к DNS. К тому же по вашему комментарию к моему ответу я понял что там всё же ваш DNS прописан: "в файле такое - domain w4u.com.ua search w4u.com.ua nameserver 5.9.36.17". Так что там в данный момент?

Comment: nameserver 192.168.0.1 - это у меня на ноутбуке так, а на сервере - domain w4u.com.ua search w4u.com.ua nameserver 5.9.36.17

Comment: @Diefair, так в этом и дело. Поставьте на ноутбуке `nameserver <IP_DNS>`. Ну или настройте 192.168.0.1, если у вас есть доступ к настройкам этого узла. Если вы настраивали bind как в инструкции, ссылку на которую вы указывали, то там должна быть опция `forwarders`, поэтому и с разрешением имён, не обслуживаемых им, тоже не должно быть проблем.

Comment: прописал на ноуте то, что вы предложили, теперь когда пишу host w4u.com.ua получаю ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41155/discussion-between-69-and-diefair).

Answer (score 1):

> Настроил bind на своем сервере

Т. е. bind на отдельном сервере, не на той же машине, откуда ping делаете?
Проверьте работу таким образом:

```
dig @<адрес_сервера_с_bind> <имя_домена> ANY
```

Т. е., к примеру, так:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 ya.ru ANY
```

Если отдаётся то, что нужно - значит сам bind работает. Вполне возможно что ваш компьютер просто не обращается к серверу, где находится bind. В таком случае стоит проверить параметры в файле /etc/resolv.conf. А так же /etc/hosts.

Воспользуйтесь так же tcpdump, что бы удостовериться, что вы получаете ответ от вашего DNS:

```
tcpdump -nn '(src IP_вашего_DNS or dst IP_вашего_DNS) and port 53'
```

Запустите в соседней консоли `host w4u.com.ua` и посмотрите - будет ли обмен пакетами с вашим сервером. Можете сократить до такой формы:

```
tcpdump -nn 'port 53'
```

что бы увидеть с кем общается ваш компьютер.

Comment: выдает то что надо. но домен не открывается. файлы /etc/resolv.conf и /etc/hosts в порядке

Comment: может у регистратора доменного имени я что то не так прописал? я создал две записи ns1 и ns2, создал для их записи типу А. и если вводить их в браузере - открывается севрер

Comment: @Diefair, *ns1 и ns2* — один из них — ваш сервер. а второй?

Comment: @Diefair, можно наглядный пример - какие NS вы указали для домена, какие на них записи, что в файле resolv.conf? Можно не реальное имя/IP, но хоть в каком-то виде, что бы понимать что и как у вас прописано.

Comment: ns1.w4u.com.ua, ns2.w4u.com.ua. в файле такое - domain w4u.com.ua
search w4u.com.ua
nameserver 5.9.36.17

Comment: @alexander barakin, тот и тот - мой сервер

Comment: @Diefair, ни `5.9.36.17`, ни `5.9.36.171` (у вас в комментарии цифра пропущена?) не отвечают на dns-запросы. в случае сетевого взаимодействия лучше бы указывать, на какой машине дело происходит (когда говорите про настройки или про «не пингуется» или про «не открывается») — на сервере или на стороннем компьютере.

Comment: да, сори, верный 5.9.36.171. я пробую со стороннего, то есть со своего компа

Comment: @Diefair, дополнил ответ, выполните предложенное и напишите результат.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

**главное**: к упомянутому вами серверу имён описанная проблема не имеет никакого отношения.

---

> Открываю на своем ноутбуке.
>   Содержимое файла /etc/resolv.conf
>   192.168.0.1
>   запустив команду на ноутбуке host w4u.com.ua получаю
>   w4u.com.ua has address 127.0.0.1

скорее всего, именно сервер имён на машине 192.168.0.1 даёт такой ответ. проверить можно такой, например, командой:

```
$ host w4u.com.ua 192.168.0.1
```

впрочем, не исключён вариант, что это имя прописано как имя компьютера. проверить можно такой, например, командой:

```
$ hostname --fqdn
```

ещё один возможный вариант — результат влияния информации из файла `/etc/hosts`. если не хотите приводить его полное содержимое, попробуйте временно закомментировать все строки (символ `#` в начале строки) и повторить запрос.

---

ещё одна гипотеза основывается на странном комментарии в приведённом файле:

```
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
```

возможно, сказывается какая-то специфика данной операционной системы.

Comment: проверил на 3х разных компах - тот же результат, так же пишет что 127.0.0.1

Comment: команда `host w4u.com.ua 192.168.0.1`? ну вот и проверяйте настройки этой машины с ip-адресом `192.168.0.1`.